# Error wile using data_usage plugin : Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED, null, null, null)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to develop an app that tracks the application data usage per each app. I am using the data_usage package and it gives me this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to request `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` for Android to collect this information. For example, use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) for it:

```dart
final permission = Permission.phone;
if (!(await permission.status.isGranted)) {
  final status = await permission.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    // User granted permission
  } else {
    // User cannot granted permission
  }
}
```

It is good, if you show a dialog with description about how you are using data that allowed to app with phone permission before you asking request for user.

Comment: i have done as what you said bt sitii i get same problem

Comment: Can you add full error message to the question?

Comment: thanks it worked,but the the problem is if i use DataUsageType.wifi it display data usage per each app but if i use DataUsageType.mobile it doesnot display how much MB Received and Sent it display 0MB to both received and Sent,

Comment: Are you have used mobile data by device? Also, you can provide bug for the plugin on plugins bug tracker on [GitHub](https://github.com/Zfinix/data_usage).